# Using a DSO138 digital oscilloscope to probe a circuit

Tags: oscilloscope, multivibrator

I'm new to using a DSO138 to probe my circuit.

In order to get the square waveform on my DSO for an astable multivibrator, do I need to connect a jumper wire from the collector of a transistor of the multivibrator to the red (positive) crocodile clip of the DSO, and do I need to connect a jumper wire from the ground in my circuit to the black crocodile clip of the DSO? Can someone please confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should clip the black lead from the DSO138 to the ground of your circuit.
- You should clip the red lead of the DSO138 to the point in the circuit that you want to observe.

Keep in mind that the load that the oscilloscope presents to the circuit may cause the circuit to misbehave.  Try to probe circuit inputs or outputs before probing things in the middle of the circuit.  Inputs and outputs can generally deal with the additional load better than the "innards" of the circuit.

Additional wires can be used, but should be kept short.  Long leads can pick up interference from other circuits or equipment.  Long leads can also act as inductors, distorting fast signals.  The DS0138 only has a bandwidth of 200kHz, though, so you shouldn't see too much "fast" stuff.

Comment: So, the red clip connected to a wire from the point I intend to measure would be fine right?